# How can I run Hello World using Serial Monitor in Tinkercad Arduino simulator?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

I want to achieve printing `Hello World` in the serial monitor using Tinkercad to simulate Arduino.

[Here](https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-hello-world) is a very simple example code for real Arduino.

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Hello World!");
}
  
void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    
}
```

However, putting an Uno board, typing this code, and clicking "Start Simulation" in Tinkercad doesn't show the `Hello World` message.

Is it doable? If so how?

For real Arduino, you need to select Arduino serial port and open Serial Monitor. But I can't find such an option for Tinkercad. I can't find Serial Monitor in Thinkercad.

My real purpose is to use Serial Monitor output to test code snippets. Right now I don't have real Arduino board with me, so I thought a simulator would be ideal. If I can easily check the values of variables, it doesn't have to be Serial Monitor.

Sorry if this is not a place to ask questions about simulators.

Comment: Did you open the Serial Monitor?

Comment: Can you provide a public link to your tinkercad simulation?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate Arduino?](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12809/how-to-simulate-arduino)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I mean where would you expect it to print `Hello World` ... On the Serial Monitor, right? So first open it by clicking on the Serial Monitor button at the bottom of the code tab in Tinkercad.

I tried your code and it works perfectly fine.

[image]

Comment: Haha! Thanks a lot, this kind of things is easy if you know where to look, but hard if you don't.